# Create CSV file from another

Tags: python, database, csv

I have a csv file as shown below:

```
19/04/2015 00:00         180         187         85         162          608          61
19/04/2015 01:00          202         20         26          70         171          61
19/04/2015 02:00          20          40         40          11          40         810
19/04/2015 03:00          20          80          81         24          0          86
19/04/2015 04:00          25          30          70          91          07          50
19/04/2015 05:00          80         611          691          70          790          37
19/04/2015 06:00         199          69          706          70          790         171
19/04/2015 07:00          80          81          90         192          57         254
19/04/2015 08:00          40         152          454         259          52         151
```

Each row is in the same cell in the file.

I'm trying to make it look like this:

```
19/04/2015 00:00   180 
19/04/2015 00:10   187
19/04/2015 00:20    85
19/04/2015 00:30   162 
19/04/2015 00:40   608
19/04/2015 00:50    61
19/04/2015 01:00   202
```

etc..

**Explaination**:

The first list of numbers is a date `dd/M/YYYY HH:mm` with 6 values, each value per 10 minutes.
In the second presentation, I wanted to have the date of each value with the exact time with minutes.

Here is what I've tried so far:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import os
import sys, getopt
import tarfile
import re
import pandas as pd
import tempfile
import shutil
import collections
import urllib
import numpy
import logging
import csv


csvFile = "testfile.csv"
data = []
minutes = ['00:00','10:00','20:00','30:00','40:00','50:00']
with open(csvFile, 'rb') as csvfile:
  reader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',')
  for row in reader:
    row[0] = re.sub("\s+", ";", row[0].strip())
    rowlist = row[0].split(';')
    while(len(rowlist)<8):
        rowlist.append(0)
    for i in range(len(rowlist)):
        for m in minutes:
            data.append(rowlist[0]+rowlist[1]+m)
            data.append(rowlist[i])
    df = pd.DataFrame(data)
    df.to_csv('example.csv')
```

But this code didn't give me the desired result.
Any suggestions?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This should work:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

in_name = 'test.csv'
out_name = 'sample.csv'

with open(in_name, 'rb') as infile, open(out_name, 'wb') as out_file:
    for line in infile:
        parts = line.split()
        date, time, data = parts[0], parts[1], parts[2:]
        hours, _ = time.split(':')

        for minutes, value in zip(range(0, 60, 10), data):
            out_file.write('{date} {hours}:{minutes:02d} {value:>5}\n'.format(
                date=date, hours=hours, minutes=minutes, value=value
            ))
```

You also had a lot of unused imports which were unnecessary and could [reduce performance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14038691/does-unused-imports-in-python-hamper-performance).

Comment: that's pretty much it. but I want to delete the first column and the first line also. How to do that?

Comment: This is a good start. OP says each value per 10 minutes. I'm not sure how using `minutes[index]` is accurate for this.

Comment: I just made an edit. Even the `pandas` import was not necessary.

Comment: Why do you use `csv` just to read in whole lines? `,` is _obviously_ not the delimiter.

Comment: @OluwafemiSule There are a fixed number of values per row, so this works. But, yes it would be better to construct that programmatically.

Comment: @hop I did make some improvements, but I'm not sure how to do this without the `csv` dependency.

Answer (score 2):

Okay I'm going to be explaining a lot in this one.

I **Highly recommend** you to use `datetime` objects if you are going to deal with dates. Because that's exactly why they are in the first place. Convert them into datetime object and you could do lots and lots of manipulations.

This a complete working code for you. I'll explain all of the concepts in depth!.

Input:

```
19/04/2015 00:00,         180 ,        187  ,       85    ,     162  ,        608 ,         61
19/04/2015 01:00,          202 ,        20  ,       26    ,      70  ,       171   ,       61
19/04/2015 02:00,          20  ,        40  ,       40    ,      11   ,       40  ,       810
```

The code:

```
import csv
from datetime import datetime,timedelta
list_of_list = []
with open("old_file.csv","r+") as my_csv:

    for line in my_csv:
        line = line.strip().replace(" ",'').split(',')
        list_of_list.append(line)



for item in list_of_list:
    dt = datetime.strptime(item[0],'%d/%m/%Y%H:%M')
    item[0]=dt

fin_list = []    
for item in list_of_list:
    temp_list = [item[0]+timedelta(minutes=10*(i)) for i,x in enumerate(item)]
    my_list = [list(a) for a in zip(temp_list,item[1:])]
    fin_list.extend(my_list)

for item in fin_list:
    item[0] = datetime.strftime(item[0],"%d/%m/%Y %H:%M")
    item[0].replace('"','')
print(fin_list)


with open("new_file.csv","w+") as my_csv:
    csvWriter = csv.writer(my_csv,delimiter=' ',quotechar = " ")
    csvWriter.writerows(fin_list)
```

output:

```
 19/04/2015  00:00  180
 19/04/2015  00:10  187
 19/04/2015  00:20  85
 19/04/2015  00:30  162
 19/04/2015  00:40  608
 19/04/2015  00:50  61
 19/04/2015  01:00  202
 19/04/2015  01:10  20
 19/04/2015  01:20  26
 19/04/2015  01:30  70
 19/04/2015  01:40  171
 19/04/2015  01:50  61
 19/04/2015  02:00  20
 19/04/2015  02:10  40
 19/04/2015  02:20  40
 19/04/2015  02:30  11
 19/04/2015  02:40  40
 19/04/2015  02:50  810
```

1) See I'm taking each row and making them into a list. Also replacing and stripping all the `whitespaces`,`\n`,`\r`

```
line = line.strip().replace(" ",'').split(',')
            list_of_list.append(line)
```

output after this:

```
['19/04/201500:00', '180', '187', '85', '162', '608']
```

2) `dt = datetime.strptime(item[0],'%d/%m/%Y%H:%M')` what's this? the `strptime` from datetime takes a string and converts it into a datetime object which you can manipulate easily.

Example:

```
>>> datetime.strptime('19/04/201500:00','%d/%m/%Y%H:%M')
>>> datetime.datetime(2015, 4, 19, 0, 0)
>>> datetime.strptime('19/04/2015 00:00','%d/%m/%Y %H:%M') #notice how this is different from above!
>>> datetime.datetime(2015, 4, 19, 0, 0)
>>> datetime.strptime('Apr 19 2015 12:00','%b %d %Y %H:%M')
>>> datetime.datetime(2015, 4, 19, 12, 0)
```

Can you see how it transformed? Once you change it into a `datetime` object you can then easily add minutes,days,hours,months anything you want with it!.

But to add them you need a `timedelta` object. Consider it like this to an `integer` you add an `integer` same way to `datetime` add `timedelta`.

```
[item[0]+timedelta(minutes=10*(i)) for i,x in enumerate(item)]
```

You might be thinking hey what the hell's this?.`enumerate` of a iterable (`list,string,tuple..etc`) gives two things i,element. Where i would be `0,1,2,3,....till last index of iterable (here list)` . So first `i,x` would be `0,item[0]` next `i,x` would be `1,item[1]` and so on.

So the list comprehension just adds `0,10,20 ,30,40,..` minutes to every datetime object.

Each item would be the below,

```
[datetime.datetime(2015, 4, 19, 0, 0), '180']
```

And finally after `extend` you get this:

```
[[datetime.datetime(2015, 4, 19, 0, 0), '180'],
 [datetime.datetime(2015, 4, 19, 0, 10), '187'],
 [datetime.datetime(2015, 4, 19, 0, 20), '85'],
 [datetime.datetime(2015, 4, 19, 0, 30), '162'],
 [datetime.datetime(2015, 4, 19, 0, 40), '608'],
 [datetime.datetime(2015, 4, 19, 0, 50), '61']]
```

How beautiful?

Now again convert the `datetime` objects to string using this,

```
item[0] = datetime.strftime(item[0],"%d/%m/%Y %H:%M")
```

So `strftime` converts it into desired format!. And alas write them in the new csv file using csv `writer`.

**Note:** This would print dates along with quotes by default!. Which you didn't want in your output so use `quotechar = " "` to remove them.